# Safe way to regularly update a local copy of a file residing on github without using a git client

Tags: php, github

My software written in PHP requires a daily update of a text file which is available on github.

I plan to use php/curl via cron, but my concern is that there is always a chance that network connection fails and the content of download can be partially damaged which will screw the purpose of my software.

Can you recommend any method how I can verify the download to be sure the downloaded file is a correct copy of the one stored in github? Because of local environment I am unable to use a git client.

Comment: you could use a script (executed via cronjob) which tries to git pull in one directory and if no error happens copy that file to your location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a call to the GitHub API.  There's an [API endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents) which provides a JSON-encoded response including a Base64-encoded content of the blob, which you can extract from the JSON.

You'll know it's intact because the JSON blob will be complete; if it's not, then your client will fail to parse the JSON.  You'll have to implement suitable error handling if the network connection fails, which you can do in most non-trivial languages.  You should also implement backoff logic in case your client gets rate-limited (that is, gets a 429).

The general raw endpoints in the web interface aren't intended for programmatic downloads, so it's not recommended to use them for automated systems.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not aware that GitHub API can be anonymous. It fully answers my needs.